# Regex - Search then add special character " in sentences with various digital numbers

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a regex way to add the " for these 2 lines :

```
    href=show0a93.html?r=c401>
    href=show8c5a.html?r=c402>
```

so that would become :

```
    href="show0a93.html?r=c401">
    href="show8c5a.html?r=c402">
```

It's easy to replace show with "show but the problem is for these 2 samples : r=c401 and r=c402 which integrates various numbers.

I searched a lot around but this just seems too difficult for me.

I tried [search for] :

```
    /^r=c[\d]>$/
```

and [replace] with :

```
   /^r=c[\d]">$/
```

and lot of other things...

Comment: Remove the `^`, that anchors at the ***beginning*** of the string.

Comment: What system/environment are you using the regex within? The replacement can be done via a capture group ..

Comment: Sorry, not sure to understand, I'm using a text edidor - TextPipe Pro and working with the "Find pattern (perl-style) filter.

Answer (score 0):

**Replace:**

```
(?<=href=)([^>]+)(?=>)
```

**With:**

```
"\1"
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=          (?# start lookbehind)
 href=        (?# match href= literally)
)             (?# end lookbehind)
(             (?# start capturing group)
 [^>]+        (?# match 1+ URL characters, everything until >)
)             (?# end capturing group)
(?=           (?# start lookahead)
 >            (?# match > literally)
)             (?# end lookahead)
```

The [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) will find expressions before and after the URL but not include them in the final match (so we don't need to worry about replacing them).  Then we [capture](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) the actual URL, which is anything but a `>` (meaning a URL with `>`, which should be encoded, would fail).  Finally, we replace the match (which is just the URL) with `"\1"`, where the `\1` references the whole URL.

**PHP:**

```
$string = '<a href=show0a93.html?r=c401>';
$string = preg_replace('/(?<=href=)([^>]+)(?=>)/', '"\1"', $string);

echo $string;
// <a href="show0a93.html?r=c401">
```

**Demo:** [Regex101](http://regex101.com/r/fF0mF2)

---

**Update:**

There is a chance that the text editor doesn't support lookarounds, in which this can still be done with a [less-elegant replacement (demo)](http://regex101.com/r/gQ1uE2):

```
href=([^>]+)>
href="\1">
```

I'm not going to go into a detailed explanation, I just removed the lookarounds which means that `href=` and `>` are now a part of the match..meaning we will need to include them when we replace everything.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, I appreaciate. I see it's working on the online regex but it doesn't work with me. It says : "You must specify all 3 decimal digits (Leading zeros are required)". I'm not even sure i'm using the right filter anyway, plus if the software I'm working with is appropriate for these kind of tasks (TextPipe Pro). I will give a go with Ultrapico Expresso working with your example.

Comment: Same message, whatever the filter i use. No result in Ultrapico Expresso either. Don't bother, I just don't know how to write it down the right way. There are few things I start to understand thank to your example, though, but it's a long way to go for me. TY again.

Comment: I have made little progress using Expresso. For : <a href=show05fd.html?r=c502>2</a>, I used the regex (?<Name>>\d) and [Replace] with ">. It gave this: <a href=show05fd.html?r=c502">2</a>. This is exactly what I wanted since any groups with the > tag (i.e </a> <div>...) are not affected by the rule plus it works with any numbers. <a href= doesn't work but this is not important since i know another way to fix the problem.